# when exactly outputSchema() gets invoked in Pig

Tags: apache-pig, udf

I am learning Pig UDFs. so please ignore any mistakes in conception.

Is it at the time of instantiating the pig udf or calling the exec() of the udf..?

Also, what is frontend and backend in Pig.. say for example:- some times we say an instance of a pig udf will be created at the frontend to verify whether Udf is proper or not. and an instance of the same udf in the backend will be created for every map task or reduce task.